# Gravitational force for a binary of point particles with GR term

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, perturbation-theory, post-newtonian

i'm trying to simulate the two body problem with 2 equal masses and I want to account for general relativistic effects. I know that the difference in the gravitational force would be an additional post Newtonian term corresponding to the quadrupole, but I can't find the exact expression for the term.

so far everything I tried to look at invoved tensorial notation which I am not familiar with. (i'm still an undergrad). and most sites consider only a central mass problem where one mass is much bigger than the other. i'm looking for a binary case so we can't neglect the smaller mass in the equations.

and in the overall what I found are these two expressions, one of which is velocity dependent:

1. $F = -\frac{GMm}{r^2} + 4\frac{G^2M^2m}{r^3c^2}$.
2. $F = K \frac{GMm}{r^2c^2}v_rV_t$  where $K$ is a constant.

are any of these two correct? or do they need adjusting?

Comment: "On the two-body problem in general relativity" "Luc Blanchet"  could you Google this, it's a pdf file that goes into excruciating details, they  do not explicitly state equal masses but they do leave the equations with $m_1$ and $m_2$ undefined. My tablet won't copy the link, my apologies.....be aware , you **will** need aspirin or coffee, it's heavy going.